# Loading UIView from UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am trying to call a UIView inside of a UITableViewController.

JHWebViewController has been created in the storybaord.

```
JHWebViewController *myWebView = [[JHWebViewController alloc] init];

NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
myWebView.request = requestObj;

[self presentViewController:myWebView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The error I get is Property 'request' not found on object of type 'JHWebViewController *'

Answer (score 1):

You can write the relevant code in UITableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath  method I hope it will work for you

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` 
{
   [self.view addSubview:myWebView.view]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You try try this:

```
JHWebViewController *myWebView = [[JHWebViewController alloc] init];

NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[myWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
myWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;

[self.view addSubview:myWebView.view];
```

Comment: Property 'view' not found on object of type 'JHWebViewController *'

Comment: JHWebViewController subclasses a UIWebView object. The word controller in the class name is kind of misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to embed the web view in a modal view controller and present the controller modally. Declare a public NSURLRequest property and set it from the table view delegate method.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` 
{
   YourEmbeddingViewController *evc = [[YourEmbeddingViewController alloc] init]; // subclass of UIViewController

   NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   evc.request = requestObj;

   [self presentViewController:evc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: I like this idea, only issue is I get an error saying the request not found on the object of my main view controller.

Comment: Maybe you just update your post to the code you are currently trying to make work.

Comment: JHWebViewController is of type UIWebView which can't be presented like a view controller. You have to make the myWebView object a UI element of the embedding view controller's view and declare a public NSURLRequest property to pass the URL to the view controller. The view controller loads the webview with the given URL.

Comment: No, I changed it so JHWebViewController is a type of UIViewController